# cannot get jquery to work in user control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

I cannot seem to get jquery to work in my user control.  I added the following code that works fine on my page but not in my user control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function selectAll() {
      debugger;
      var checkBoxSelectorAll = '#<%=mGridView.ClientID%> input[id*="chkSelectAll"]:checkbox';
      var checkBoxSelectorRows = '#<%=mGridView.ClientID%> input[id*="chkSelected"]:checkbox';
      $(checkBoxSelectorRows).attr('checked', $(checkBoxSelectorAll).is(":checked"));
   }
</script>
```

but when I call it from my checkbox, it can't find "selectAll()".

So I tried to register it using this in my Page_Load:

```
     StringBuilder scriptText = new StringBuilder();
     scriptText.Append("<script>   function selectAll() {");
     scriptText.Append("var checkBoxSelectorAll = '#<%=mGridView.ClientID%> input[id*=\"chkSelectAll\"]:checkbox';");
     scriptText.Append("var checkBoxSelectorRows = '#<%=mGridView.ClientID%> input[id*=\"chkSelected\"]:checkbox';");
     scriptText.Append("$(checkBoxSelectorRows).attr('checked', $(checkBoxSelectorAll).is(\":checked\"));");
     scriptText.Append("alert('Literal Added to <Head>.');");
     scriptText.Append("}</script>");

     Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
                "CounterScript", scriptText.ToString(), false);
```

I added the Alert just to see if it was working and if I comment out the "$(checkBoxSelectorRows)", it goes to the alert fine.  If I add the line back in I get:

```
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 14519 in http://localhost:58458/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=mGridView.ClientID%> input[id*="chkSelected"]:checkbox
```

I thought maybe the "$" was causing the problem so I added this to the markup page at the top:

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

But I get the same error.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I don't think `<%=` gets rendered from the server side; the string gets treated as is. You have to hard-code the IDs if you're generating the script on the server (or if you have access to the controls you can try to get the IDs at runtime).

Comment: But I only get the error if I comment out the jquery line.

Comment: The javascript should be fine in the markup on the usercontrol.  The server should render <%=mGridView.ClientID%> just fine as long as the gridview is on the usercontrol with the javascript.  If you have code on the container page that can't find your function on the usercontrol, i am curious when that code is being called?  could it be running too early before the page is fully loaded?  I would add some console.log()'s to see what's going on and make sure it's loaded before you try to call it.